# Undefined method on an instance variable that is very much defined? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, jquery-mobile

I'm getting this classic error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass):
    34:             </li>
    35:             <%end%>
    36: 
    37:             <%if @today_jobs.count == 0 %>
```

But in the lines above that:

```
    <%if @accepted_jobs.count == 0 %>
```

And in the controller:

```
@accepted_jobs = Job.where({:status => ["2", "4"],:admin_id => session[:user_id].to_s})
@today_jobs = Job.where({:status => "2",:admin_id=>session[:user_id].to_s,:start_date => Date.to_mongo(Date.today) })
```

So both of these variables are defined, not that different, yet my app can "remember" the value of one of them and forgets the value of the other.

I'm sure it's something very simple I'm overlooking - but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: The error message is very much true. Reproduce minimally: `nil.count`; now, with that out of the way, it's just a question of *why* said variable evaluates to `nil`. Some cases to explore: 1) the assignment was never done *that request*; 2) the variable was reassigned later; 3) Job.where returns nil. I suspect the issue is #1.

Comment: @user2246674 You are correct - the assignment wasn't being done on the request I thought it was being done on - it was too obvious to see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says `undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass` which means that `@accepted_jobs` is nil. The `nil:NilClass` part is the clue here.

You can rewrite it to say something like:

```
<% if @today_jobs?
  <% if @today_jobs.count == 0 %>
   ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a correct answer.  My actual problem was that I was defining @today_jobs in the index but not in the show method which was the thing being rendered when I went back to the home page (as opposed to displaying on first login).  I'm giving you the check because your way would also have worked.